# Only replace a string only once in the entire file

Tags: string, sed

I have a file that I wish to only replace a string only once in the entire file IE the first match it finds should be replaced. 
sed -i 's/foo/foo1/1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following:

```
sed -i '0,/foo/s//foo1/' file
```

Here,

`/foo/` will fetch line number of the first occurrence of *foo*, let's say `#n`

Then the same word will be searched *till line* `#n` and replaced by `foo1`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '!f{f=sub(/foo/,"foo1")} 1' file
```